# Backbone refresh/bookmark page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I have a webpage that I'm using Backbone to make it into a Single Page App thingy but refreshing a page or following a bookmark doesn't work - the JS says it is undefined etc.

This is a stripped down version for simplicity

```js
this.LeBaron = new function() {
  this.Routing = new function() {
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "index": "index",
        "other": "other"
      },

      index: function() {
        view("index", {});
      },
      other: function() {
        view("other", {});
      }
    });

    var view = function(id, model) {
      $("#content").html($("#" + id).html());

    }
    this.router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>
    Single Page Test
  </title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/backbone-min-1-1-2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">

  </div>

  <a href="#/index">  Index </a>
  <br />
  <a href="#/other"> Other </a>
</body>
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="index">
    <p>Index Page!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="other">
    <p>Other Page!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `new` before your constructor

```js
var LeBaron = this.LeBaron = function() {
  this.Routing = function() {
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "index": "index",
        "other": "other"
      },

      index: function() {
        view("index", {});
      },

      other: function() {
        view("other", {});
      }
    });

    var view = function(id, model) {
      $("#content").html($("#" + id).html());

    };

    this.router = new Router();

    Backbone.history.start();
  };
  
  this.Routing();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  new LeBaron();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>
    Single Page Test
  </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">

  </div>

  <a href="#/index">  Index </a>
  <br />
  <a href="#/other"> Other </a>
</body>
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="index">
    <p>Index Page!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="other">
    <p>Other Page!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: That stops the code from working at all :( the content div doesn't get filled and I have no error messages either as to why.

I've always gotten confused over the "new" in javascript - I'm a little too used to Java and such like that javascript always confuses me

Comment: You should create constructor first, _then_ invoke it with new keyword

Comment: Ok perfect - that's solved the issue and I've gotten the full scale site working as it should as well locally - needed a few minor tweaks as other stuff didn't like the changes but was probably my fault for doing things wrong in the first place/